# Class 'Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider' not found during Google App Engine Deployment

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Generating optimized autoload files
Step #1: > Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
Step #1: > @php artisan package:discover
Step #1:
Step #1: In Application.php line 638:
Step #1:
Step #1:   Class 'Laravel\Dusk\DuskServiceProvider' not found
Step #1:
Step #1:
Step #1: Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
Step #1: error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1

When deploying my application to google app engine

Answer (score 0):

The `DuskServiceProvider` is usually only registered when composer dev dependencies are installed, it appears that when you are deploying to Google App Engine it is not installing any of your composer dev dependencies.

You'll either a) want to make sure that you are not registering the `DuskServiceProvider` manually anywhere in your code, b) running any tests which rely on the the Dusk package, or c) ensure your deployment script is also installing the dev dependencies.